# How can i find the last number in tags

Tags: regex, python-2.7, pattern-matching

for passing the pagination of a site with python, i want to find the last page of a website.
i inspect the element of the page by **firebug**

```
<div class="pagination">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                                <a>
                                    <img src="/images" class="pagination-l">
                                </a>
                    </li>
                            <li style="float:left;">
                                <a id="toPage" title="A" class="page-number actif" href="/d">
                                    1
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="float:left;">
                                <a id="toPage_0" title="A2" class="p" href="/ew">
                                    2
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="float:left;">
                                <a id="toPage_1" title="A3" class="p3" href="/t3">
                                    3
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="float:left;">...</li>
                            <li style="float:left;">
                                <a id="toPage_2" title="t" class="p" href="t2">
                                    5
                                </a>
                            </li>
                    <li>
                            <a id="nextPage" title="next(2)" href="/test1">
                                <img src="test.png" class="pagination-r">
                            </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

Here the number that i want is **5**

Comment: One word: [**BeautifulSoup**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: @jan i don't know the id of the last page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of a parser and regex:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = your_html_here

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
links = soup.findAll('a', text=re.compile('^\s*\d+\s*$'))
number = links[-1].string.strip()
print number
# 5
```

See a  <kbd>[demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/o59vBZ)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for answer and demo